# Magento2 catalog product edit related

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.4.3, modifier

I am trying to override Related in the product edit to remove it but it does not work

In my file etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="roles-related" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

In my file php

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class Related extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related
{
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $checkNumber = 1;

        if ($checkNumber == 1) {
            unset($meta[static::GROUP_RELATED]);
        }

        return $meta;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your modifier does not remove the Related config from the `$meta` because its sort order is smaller than the sort order of the **Related** modifier (sortOrder 110). As a result, your modifier (sortOrder 10) is loaded before the Related modifier declares the Related node config.

To achieve your need, you'll need to set the sortOrder for your modifier to a number higher than 110.

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="roles-related" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">120</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Recompile the code (bin/magento setup:di:compile) to see the result.

Note: `$meta[static::GROUP_RELATED]` does not only contain the config for the Related Products, but also for  Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells.
Therefore, if you only need to remove the Related Products config, you'll need to use the following code:

```
unset($meta[static::GROUP_RELATED]['children'][static::DATA_SCOPE_RELATED]);
```

Check out the `modifyMeta` method in the `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related` class for reference.

Comment: thank you sir, and can i ask you 1 small question. Can we hide Product Salable Quantity look like Related by this way ?

Comment: @Boll I just saw your new post about this, I have provided the solution in that post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369838/magento2-remove-product-salable-qty