# Magento2 remove Product Salable Qty

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1

Can we remove this tab in product edit view

i have override this file i have xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="roles-salable-qty" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\SalableQuantity</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

and i have file SalableQuantity

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


class SalableQuantity extends \Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\SalableQuantity
{
 
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
      $numberCheck = 5;

            if ($numberCheck==5) {
                $meta['salable_quantity'] = [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'disabled' => true
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ];
            }

        return $meta;
    }

   
}
```

I hope can someone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort order of the **SalableQuantity** modifier is 300.
vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="salable_quantity" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\SalableQuantity</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">300</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

To override the **SalableQuantity** modifier, you need to set the sort order value of your modifier to a higher value than the sort order of the **SalableQuantity**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="roles-salable-qty" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">YourVendor\YourModule\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\SalableQuantity</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">310</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Recompile the code (bin/magento setup:di:compile) to see results.